# twitter feed api

Tags: java, twitter, feed

I need an application built that accesses Twitter feeds and stores it into a log file using java.

And if possible there should be some control that allows to track the keywords where we can filter the data in the log file.

How to start? Is it like RSS feed? I don't have any idea. Please help me out.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `Twitter4J`as a start. The library project is OpenSource.

You can find it with examples here : https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j